# Invalid Hook Call for custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have written a function for API calls. I want to reuse this function from a different page.

**FetchData.js**

```js
export const FetchData = (url, query, variable) => {
    const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const queryResult = await axios.post(
                url, {
                query: query,
                variables: variable
            }
            )
            const result = queryResult.data.data;
            setFetchData(result.mydata)
        };

        fetchData();
    })

    return {fetchData, setFetchData}

}
```

Here is my main page from where I am trying to call the API using the following code

**mainPage.js**

```js
import { FetchData } from './FetchData'

export const MainPage = props => {

    const onClick = (event) => {
        const {fetchData, setFetchData} = FetchData(url, query, variable)
        console.log(fetchData)
    }
}
```

It is returning the following error -

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Hooks can't be used inside handler functions.

Comment: Btw, your `useEffect` runs every render because you didn't add the second argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to fetch data on response to an event, you don't need a useEffect.

```js
const useData = (url, query, variable) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const queryResult = await axios.post(url, {
      query: query,
      variables: variable,
    });
    setData(queryResult.data.data);
  };
  
  return {data, fetchData}
};

export const MainPage = (props) => {
  const {data, fetchData} = useData(url, query, variable);
  const onClick = (event) => {
    fetchData()
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case, the data is not updated immediately. For this I tried to add a second Argument (with a function). That is giving me an error `State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument.` Hence I tried to use a `useEffect` in the function which is giving me an error that `useEffect` can not be used in functions.

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at this article: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/ , there is a quite complete example of a custom hook used for data fetching

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can't be used inside handler functions.

Do this instead:

```
import { FetchData } from './FetchData'

export const MainPage = props => {
    const {fetchData, setFetchData} = FetchData(url, query, variable)
    const onClick = (event) => {
         console.log(fetchData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Custom hooks (which is what `FetchData` is) should have a name starting with `use`, not with a capital letter, otherwise it looks like a component.